# How to set page number in right side in chapter title page?

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, footer

I need to setup page number right side of the footer. It's ok in the second page of a chapter.

But in chapter title page, page number showing in the center of that page.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\huge \textbf{ Abstract}}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\lipsum[2-4]
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[L]{\textit{\chaptername\thechapter}}

\chapter{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Unrelated: do you really want to have `Chapter 1` on both sides of the header?

Comment: No. I don't need that . Acutally i need chapter 1 in left and chapter name such as Introduction on right. But this is not the problem for me.

Comment: Add `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after of `\chapter{...}`

Comment: With your code, you obtain `Chapter1` on the left and `CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTiON` on th right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you load `titlesec`, it's much simpler to load it with option `pagestyles` and use `titleps`. You have to redefine the `plain` page style, which is used in the first page of a chapter. Redefining a page style is particularly easy with `titleps`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\headrule
\sethead{\itshape\chaptername\thechapter}{}{\itshape\chaptertitle}
\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}%

\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1cm}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{mine}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine. But facing another problem when i add another page before chapter such as Abstract page, it is showing chapter 0 in the heading. I don't need that. I have update MWE please check.

Comment: Will your real abstract fit on a single page?

Comment: Yes. only in single page

Comment: Why don't you use  `\chapter{Abstract}` in this case? It would use the redefined plain page style.

Answer (score 5):

You need to redefine the page style `plain` used on the chapter title page like:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% <==============================================
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
```

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[%
  left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,
  includefoot,heightrounded
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1cm}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% <==============================================
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[L]{\textit{\chaptername\thechapter}}

\chapter{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

you get:

[image]

## Update:

To add an chapter/abstract before chapter 1 please change your used code to:

```
%\begin{center} % <======================================================
\chapter*{Abstract} % <============================= usualy not numbered!
%\end{center}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\lipsum[2-4] % <========================================================
```

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[%
  left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,
  includefoot,heightrounded
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1cm}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% <==============================================
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[L]{\textit{\chaptername\thechapter}}

%\begin{center} % <======================================================
\chapter*{Abstract}
%\end{center}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\lipsum[2-4] % <========================================================

\chapter{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\lipsum[2-4]
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

you get then:

[image: abstract]

Comment: It works fine. But facing another problem when i add another page before chapter such as Abstract page, it is showing chapter 0 in the heading. I don't need that. I have update MWE please check

Comment: @Alamin Please see my updated answer ...