# Why need to redefine `main` pagestyle even if another pagestyle is in use?

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, titleps

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482470/207649) answer explains how to center the page numbers on the chapter pages, which are not centered even after the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{myPageStyle}[\scshape]{
    \setfoot[\thepage][][]
    {}{}{\thepage}
}

\pagestyle{myPageStyle}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Call me by your name}
    \lipsum[1-10]
    \chapter{Elio}
    \lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

The solution that is given is to also renew the `plan` pagestyle as follows:

```latex
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}%
```

**Question**: Does that mean that on chapter pages, `main` pagestyle is applied? <s>But if so, I can say that it is only applied in the footer, for if I do `\sethead` as well in defining `myPageStyle`, headers do get modified on the chapter pages. But this seems awkward. What is actually happening?</s>

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. as you see chapters do `\thispagestyle{plain}` so you need to set that page style to customise chapter opening pages

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops! Yes, I mentioned some incorrect observations in my Question. Striking those out. And your comment clears up my Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapters in many document classes do `\thispagestyle{plain}` so you need to set that page style to customise chapter opening pages.